# Nested item in json array is not being deserialized

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a json string from an api.

All works except for a nested item - Location which always ends up null

This is the string structure:

```json
[
    {
        "CompanyProfile": "<p>A&amp;B Inc etc...</p>",
        "Address": "56 Test Street, Test, UK",
        "Location": {
            "Latitude": 61.52787,
            "Longitude": -4.32095,
            "Zoom": 13,
            "Icon": null,
            "Format": 0,
            "Api": null,
            "SearchTyped": null
        },
        "Id": 1723,
        "Name": "A&B Inc"
    },
        {
        "CompanyProfile": "<p>B&amp;C Inc etc...</p>",
        "Address": "57 Test Street, Test, UK",
        "Location": {
            "Latitude": 61.2122,
            "Longitude": -4.31111,
            "Zoom": 13,
            "Icon": null,
            "Format": 0,
            "Api": null,
            "SearchTyped": null
        },
        "Id": 1723,
        "Name": "B&C Inc"
    },
]
```

These are the classes to map to:

```
public class MemberDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? CompanyProfile { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public Location? Location { get; internal set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

This is the deserialize code:

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var members = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MemberDto>>(result);
```

I know I can use `ReadFromJsonAsync<List<MemberDto>>()` as well but using ReadFromString so I can check the json before deserializing. Anyway the result is exactly the same for ReadFromJsonAsync.

Everything except Location is deserialized successfully

Anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Remove _internal_: public Location? Location { get; internal set; }
______
public Location? Location { get; set; }

Comment: Why Location setter is internal?

Comment: Make your life easy; take your JSON, paste it into https://app.quicktype.io and follow the instructions in the comment header of the generated code; paste the generated code back into your app and put the one line of code from the header into the approppriate place in your app code (`var members = YourRootObjectName.FromJson(result)`)

Comment: @McNets - that was it!!! internal set  - I think resharper must have put it there.  Not sure why it is there.  If you add as answer, I select it as correct.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer - thanks also for spotting answer

Comment: I had this same issue two days ago. It's the caveat where when you auto-add properties to a class (via quick refactoring) the setter is made internal by default. Terrible design choice by MS, because it causes these kinds of issues. (Mine was with asp.net model binding)

Comment: And please don't edit the answer/ solution into the question. That's not how Stack Overflow works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the internal access modifier in the setter of Location.

```
public Location? Location { get; set; }
```

Comment: To add upon the answer: In general, for the deserialization to work, the setter should be public. So any non-public modifier, like `internal`, `protected`, `private` should be removed.